# How to use localization for a table view cell with custom class?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a `TableViewController` with a `TableView` and a standard `TableViewCell` in it.

[image]

If I configure the `TableViewCell` as style `Basic`, I can use a storyboard localization file (*.strings) to translate the label of the basic cell. This works well.

**storyboard.strings**:

```
"xAt-2c-UqjT.text" = "My Translated Text";
```

[image]

However, if I use a `Custom Class` for the label, the localization file is not considered anymore for this label and the translation is not applied.

The custom class extends `UILabel` and looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomLabel : UILabel {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setStyle()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()

        setStyle()
    }

    func setStyle() {
        self.font = FontConstants.NORMAL
        self.textColor = ColorConstants.TEXT_NORMAL
    }
}
```

Why is the translation not working anymore for a custom label even though the label extends `UILabel`?

**Update**: Maybe it is worth noting that the `CustomLabel` will be translated correctly in all other usages other than inside a `TableViewCell`.

Comment: You could check this: http://blog.xebia.com/ios-localization-tricks-for-storyboard-and-nib-files/

Comment: I experience the problem the other way round. Storyboard translation works fine for a custom cell with a label inside, but it doesn't translate my cells that are of style "basic" :-(

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `super` on `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`:

`super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Configure the TableViewCell as style `Custom` instead